# How to get firebase real-time database usage programmatically

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

Is there any API available for getting real-time database usage.
We need to show usage and related info on our dashboard and my client don't want to visite firebase consol and option for the upgrade or downgrade plan programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no API for this.  You may file a feature request [here](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features).