# How to get Firebase Database quota usage in code?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, quota

I want to be able to tell how much of my Firebase Database quota I have used inside my Javascript code. Is this possible?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114242/firebase-realtime-database-detailed-usage, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52621113

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase doesn't provide any client APIs to query the billable usage of any Firebase product.  However, you can [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).  You can also record for yourself an estimate of your usage, and query that.